# Why object is becoming null when accessed out of thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following program I'm inserting

> files[i].lastModified() value in allFiles HashMap in RThread class

when I tried to retrive the value of lastModified from allFiles HashMap in the main class the value is coming as null. So instead of lastModified value I placed File object directly in HashMpa then it worked.

Anyone guide me the concept behind this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class RCFLister {

    ConcurrentHashMap allFiles = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    String fileType = null;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RCFLister rcFileLister = new RCFLister();
        rcFileLister.recentFiles(args);
    }

    public void recentFiles(String[] args) {

        int days = 1;
        ThreadGroup rootthreadGr = new ThreadGroup("rootsThreadGroup");
        // reading number of days
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null) {
            days = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        }
        // reading file type
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null) {
            fileType = args[1];
        }
        fileType = "png";
        // fileextFilter = new FileExtensionFilter(fileType);
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();
        List threads = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(roots[i].getAbsolutePath());
            // rfThread = null;

            RThread rfThread = new RThread(roots[i]);
            Thread t = new Thread(rfThread);
            t.start();
            threads.add(t);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
            try {
                ((Thread) threads.get(i)).join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   

        ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(allFiles);
        TreeMap sortedMap = new TreeMap(vc);
        sortedMap.putAll(allFiles);
        System.out.println(sortedMap.size());
        Iterator it = sortedMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object key = it.next();
            System.out.println(key + " " + sortedMap.get(key));
        }
    }

    private class ValueComparator implements Comparator {

        Map allFiles;

        public ValueComparator(Map allFiles) {
            this.allFiles = allFiles;
        }

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if (((Long) allFiles.get(o1)) >= ((Long) allFiles.get(o2))) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private class RThread implements Runnable {
        File rootFolder;



        RThread(File root) {
            rootFolder = root;          
        }

        public void run() {
            getFiles(rootFolder);

        }

        public void getFiles(File folder) {
            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; files != null && i < files.length; i++) {
                // System.out.println(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    getFiles(files[i]);
                } else if (fileType == null
                        || (fileType != null && files[i].getName().endsWith(
                                fileType))) {
                    String filename = null;
                    try {
                        filename = files[i].getCanonicalPath();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                                                 if(files[i].lastModified()!=0)
                    allFiles.put(filename, files[i].lastModified());
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: your question is not clear? how and where do you check that files[i].lastModified() value is coming as  null? I tried to print the map and they are not null

Comment: Please use generics when dealing with maps. Java 5 was released more than 8 years ago.

Comment: inside RThread the value is not null but outside the thread it is null when I'm reading the main class System.out.println(key + " " + sortedMap.get(key));

Answer (score 0):

compare() method of ValueComparator never returns 0. Return 0 means equality which is missing so even if key is present it is not found. 
Also the key is String(filename) and you are comparing by value (long). Need to rethink how you want to store data. 
Just to make sure it is only problem, print CocurrentHashMap.

Do use Generic, it looks tedious at beginning but is really not that bad. It will help to compiler code without warning and achieve type safety.